# The bitmap generated by freetype2 on android, the text will repeat, how to solve it

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, freetype

I use FreeType 2.10.2 to render text on Android. Now the bitmap is generated, but there are multiple (4) repeated texts. The picture is as follows:

[image: chapters11_error10]

The rendered text is "G", where the black range is the size of the bitmap, but there is a problem. First, there are four "G" in the bitmap, and then the text "G" does not fill the entire bitmap. I don't know why this is, here is the code:

```c
int initTexture() {
    if (init) return -1;

    FT_Face face;
    FT_Library ft;

    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
    FT_New_Face(ft, fontPathNativeString, 0, &face);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 12 * 12);

    FT_ULong wChar = textUnicodeString[0];
    FT_Load_Char(face, wChar, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);

    FT_GlyphSlot glyph = face->glyph;
    FT_Render_Glyph(glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RGBA,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
    );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    characterTextureID = texture;

    GLfloat xpos = 0 + face->glyph->bitmap_left;
    GLfloat ypos = 500 + (face->glyph->bitmap.rows - face->glyph->bitmap_top);

    GLfloat scale = 5.0f;

    GLfloat w = face->glyph->bitmap.width / surfaceWidth * scale;
    GLfloat h = face->glyph->bitmap.rows * scale / surfaceHeight;

    xpos = (xpos - surfaceWidth) / surfaceWidth;
    ypos = (surfaceHeight - ypos) / surfaceHeight;

    GLfloat vertices[24] = {
            xpos, ypos, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            xpos, ypos - h, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            xpos + w, ypos - h, 1.0f, 1.0f,

            xpos, ypos, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            xpos + w, ypos - h, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            xpos + w, ypos, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);

    init = 1;

    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_me_excq_androidopengles20demo_chapters11_MyRenderer02_drawFrame(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    initTexture();

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glUseProgram(programID);

    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ourTextColor"), 0.5, 0.8, 0.2);

    GLuint vertexHandle = (GLuint) glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertex");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, characterTextureID);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
}
```

and my vertex shader code is:

```c
attribute vec4 vertex;

varying vec2 outTexCoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  outTexCoord = vertex.zw;
}
```

I wrote it according to [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering/)(LearnOpenGL - Text Rendering), but I don’t know why this happens, how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you closely look at the image, then you can see, that the 4 characters are different:

[image]

What seems to be 4 characters, actually is 1 character, splitted in parts.

The issue is caused by the fact, that `FT_Render_Glyph` generates an image, with 1 channel rather than an RGBA image. Hence the format argument to [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) hast to be `GL_RED`,  `GL_LUMINANCE` or `GL_ALPHA`:

```
glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RED,
        face->glyph->bitmap.width,
        face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
        0,
        GL_RED,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
);
```

Comment: Yes, after changing the format parameter of the `glTexImage2D` function to`GL_LUMINANCE`, the display is normal. Thank you very much.